# landscape в android

Tags: java, android

как сделать, чтобы в андроиде когда запускаешь приложение открывалось сразу в албомной форме

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408197/android-landscape-only-orientation) это уже давно обсудили. Читай.

Comment: спасибо заработало